# Servicestack service fail to use HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, servicestack

I have REST API service using Servicetack.Service in ServiceStack.AppHost.
One of my web services is calling other 3rd party's web service. When it call the 3rd party using HttpClient I get this exception:
*System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException HResult=0x80131501 Message=A call to SSPI failed, Inner Exceptin: Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.*
**This code is working just fine on ApiController.** But I want to migrate my code to use ServiceStack.Service

This is my post method that call to other post http service:

```
public object Post(MyRequest info)
{
    var myJsonRequest = "Building Json from request info....";
    using (var cl = new HttpClient())
    {
        var result = cl.PostAsync("http://3rdpartyurl:999/someservice",
            new StringContent(myJsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        return result.StatusCode;
    }

}
```

I tried to replace use of HttpClient with WebRequest and JsonServiceClient but I get the same exception.

Comment: " The message received was unexpected or badly formatted. " sound likes you request and the server are talking in different ssl protocols... can you check what ssl protocol have the server and after try to force your code to use that protocol ...